# Fanned confidence interval for PACF plot in R

Tags: r, time-series, advanced-custom-fields, lag, confidence-interval

I have a PACF plot that looks like the following:

[image: PACF]

I am wondering why my 95% confidence interval stays the same across my time lags?  As my time lag increases, I have less data, and thus my confidence should decrease, and my intervals should INCREASE.  So shouldn't I get confidence interval lines that fan out like so (Screenshot taken from Ben Bolker's GLMM worked example - http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/10858_19492a31e76245e292aaaae235d3efa8.html):

[image]

I am simply using pacf(residuals(data),retype="normalized").  Is there a way to customize the CI so that it takes into account reduced CI at each time lag?